# Pagination of Stargate document API for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

The Stargate Document API for Cassandra provides page-size to return all documents limited by a page size. The page-size is has max value of 20. How do I get the next documents; i.e 21 to 30?

[Reading Documents using Stargate API for Cassandra](https://stargate.io/docs/stargate/1.0/developers-guide/document-using.html#_reading_documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when you run your query for the initial 20, you'll get a property in the returned JSON called
`pageState`.  Here's an example with `page-size=5`:

```
% curl --request GET \
  --url https://$ASTRA_DB_ID-$ASTRA_DB_REGION.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/namespaces/$ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE/collections/hello_docs\?page-size\=5 \
  -H "X-Cassandra-Token: $ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{"pageState":"JGNlYjczMDc5LTE1NTItNGQyNS1hM2ExLWE2MzgxNWVlYTAyMADwf_____B_____","data":{
"58b12778-0efd-466e-89bf-66a4c99adee1":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"Red Rabbit"},
"77fe8690-f8d4-43b8-b1c9-a328318d4eae":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"Every Man a Tiger"},
"3177f86c-a633-4302-92a5-de4c15ab5840":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"Rainbow Six"},
"cefc7117-fc73-47b8-a965-099cf3a59269":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"Clear and Present Danger"},
"ceb73079-1552-4d25-a3a1-a63815eea020":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"The Cardinal of the Kremlin"}}}%
```

When I want to get the next 5 documents, I re-run the same query but add the `page-state` parameter with the value returned from the previous results:

```
&page-state\=JGNlYjczMDc5LTE1NTItNGQyNS1hM2ExLWE2MzgxNWVlYTAyMADwf_____B_____
```

When I add that to the original query, it looks like this:

```
% curl --request GET \
--url https://$ASTRA_DB_ID-$ASTRA_DB_REGION.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/namespaces/$ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE/collections/hello_docs\?page-size\=5\&page-state\=JGNlYjczMDc5LTE1NTItNGQyNS1hM2ExLWE2MzgxNWVlYTAyMADwf_____B_____ \
-H "X-Cassandra-Token: $ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'

 {"pageState":"JDUxMzVmMzFiLWY4NDYtNGZiNy1iNmFmLTk2YmU2OTMyNzlmMQDwf_____B_____","data":{
"f42cc7d8-81ba-41d5-b5c9-c13f8d0009c6":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"Patriot Games"},
"46df315f-7208-4859-af1c-96c4953f70c7":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"Without Remorse"},
"b23af545-4fdc-4ac5-907a-7132d7429d26":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"The Hunt for Red October"},
"c6d55ecd-1631-4d5c-8320-d111662f8837":{"other":"This is nonsensical stuff.","title":"Some Stuff"},
"5135f31b-f846-4fb7-b6af-96be693279f1":{"author":"Tom Clancy","title":"The Sum of all Fears"}}}%
```

**tl;dr;**

Add the `pageState` returned in the results, and you should get the next 20.

**Edit 20211011**

The Stargate documentation has been updated with detail to address this process.

[Retrieving all documents with Paging](https://stargate.io/docs/stargate/1.0/developers-guide/document-using.html#_retrieving_all_documents_with_paging)